# Java Logback log level is ERROR. But seeing INFO, WARN and DEBUG logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

I have the below logback configuration in my springboot code. The log level at root and at the application level is set to be 'ERROR'. But still seeing WARN, DEBUG and INFO level logs.

I can see the logback file to be used by the framework and the details in the configuration like file_name, file format are reflecting in logs but the level alone is not reflecting

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
        <Marker>TraceMarker</Marker>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </turboFilter>

    <appender name="SERVICE_NAME" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>service_xyz.log</file>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - [%marker] %msg %n</pattern>
        </layout>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>service_xyz.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>240</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_NAME" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.xyz.service" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_NAME" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

I can also see the logging levels set up properly in the logger logs.

```
INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR

INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@797b0699 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework

INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SERVICE_NAME] to Logger[ROOT]

INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.xyz.service] to ERROR

INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@797b0699 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[com.xyz.service] onto the JUL framework
```

Comment: Not sure if the config file is case-sensitive or not. Ever tried `level="error"`?